# How to change value of href on some button click in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have seen on some websites that there are two or three buttons, and below there is a box showing link or an  tag.

When I click first button, it will change the href attribute to link 1.
When I click on second button, the same href attribute will be automatically change to link 2. 
And same for button three.

I want to know how can I do this on my website. I have five different products, I want customers to first select their desired product and then click on the order button. Order button's link should be changed according to the selection made.

I have seen this function on this website https://www.webxen.com/

Please help me I don't know exactly what I should ask. If there is a tutorial or something on this then please share, or help me in developing this.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be how you can alter the href attribute.
This is the same as altering every attribute.

Let's say you have the following element:

```
<a id="link" href="link1"><p>Link</p></a>
```

You can simply change the href tag using

```
document.getElementById("link").href = "link2"
```

Next time when asking a question, try to provide some code or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This may look like what you are looking for:

```
<a id="link" href="link"><p>Link</p></a>

<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>

$('#button1').on('click', function(){

    $('#link').attr('href','link1');


});

$('#button2').on('click', function(){

    $('#link').attr('href','link2');


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mvhfc8jh/